# Saving to the same parquet file in parallel using dask leading to ArrowInvalid

Tags: python, pyspark, io, dask, parquet

I am doing some simulation where I compute some stuff for several time step. For each I want to save a parquet file where each line correspond to a simulation this looks like so :

```py
def simulation():
    nsim = 3
    timesteps = [1,2]
    data = {} #initialization not shown here
    for i in nsim:
        compute_stuff()
        for j in timesteps:
            data[str(j)]= compute_some_other_stuff()

    return data
```

Once I have my dict `data` containing the result of my simulation (under numpy arrays), I transform it into `dask.DataFrame` objects to then save them to file using the `.to_parquet()` method as follows:

```py
def save(data):
    for i in data.keys():
        data[i] = pd.DataFrame(data[i], bins=...)
        df = from_pandas(data[i], npartitions=2)
        f.to_parquet(datafolder + i + "/", engine="pyarrow", append=True, ignore_divisions = True)
```

When use this code only once it works perfectly and the struggle arrises when I try to implement it in parallel. Using dask I do:

```py
client = Client(n_workers=10, processes=True)

def f():
   data = simulation()
   save(data)

to_compute = [delayed(f)(n) for n in range(20)]
compute(to_compute)
```

The behaviour of this last portion of code is quite random. At some point this happens:

```
distributed.worker - WARNING - Compute Failed
Function:  f
args:      (4)
kwargs:    {}
Exception: "ArrowInvalid('Parquet file size is 0 bytes')"
....

distributed.worker - WARNING - Compute Failed
Function:  f
args:      (12)
kwargs:    {}
Exception: "ArrowInvalid('Parquet magic bytes not found in footer. Either the file is corrupted or this is not a parquet file.')"
```

I think these errors are due to the fact that 2 processes try to write at the same time to the same parquet file, and it not well handled (as it can be on txt file). I already tried to switch to pySpark / Koalas without much success. I there a better way to save the result along a simulation (in case of a crash / wall time on a cluster)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a classic dask mistake of invoking the dask API from within functions that are themselves delayed. The error indicates that things are happening in parallel (which is what dask does!) which are not expected to change during processing. Specifically, a file is clearly being edited by one task while another one is reading it (not sure which).

What you probably want to do, is use `concat` on the dataframe pieces and then a single call to to_parquet.

Note that it seems all of your data is actually held in the client, and you are using from_parquet. This seems like a bad idea, since you are missing out on one of dask's biggest features, to only load data when needed. You should, instead, load your data inside delayed functions or dask dataframe API calls.

Comment: To clarify I am not loading the data but creating it through a kind of Monte Carlo simulation and I need to aggregate lots of data

```python
for _ in range(1000):
    #Doing the main simulation 60 times
    result = [delayed(simu)(i) for i in range(60)] 
    result = compute(result)

   #For each key I use concat to create bigger array
    keys = result[0][0].keys()
    to_save = [delayed(save_key)(result,n) for n in keys]
    to_save = compute(to_save, num_workers=5)
    for df  in to_save[0]:
        df.to_parquet(...)

```